# receive wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) when entering will_pagenate method in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, will-paginate

I followed the will_paginate instructions, (https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), to install and use the gem but when I put the `<%= will_paginate @comments %>` in the views I receive an error. everything before hand works according to all the videos I hav seen but I am not sure how else I can approach this

this is my git
https://github.com/adriandabi/DABI

I have tried all the options it tells me, even putting self.per_page = 2 in the comment model

in my _comments partial(which is being rendered to products show):

```
<%= will_paginate @comments %>
```

in my product_controller:

```
def show
  @comments = @product.comments.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
end
```

I should be getting page links as well as a next and previous link,
but instead I am receiving an argument error 
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Comment: Show the whole error log

Comment: I literally jus solved it after asking the question lol, I just updated my will_paginate gem to 3.1.7

Comment: then post the answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Updating your Version of `will_paginate` will most likely fix the issue (As @adrian-dabi suggests in his comment). The previous versions got kind of old. `3.1.6` is around 2-3 years old.

We ran into this issue updating a legacy rails app from Version ~5.1 to ~5.2